# Selenium Webdriver opening links in new window when manually it opens in new tab

Tags: selenium

When I run through a test manually on my machine and click a link that link is opened in a new tab, however when I run the test through in Selenium it opens it up in a new window which is incredibly frustrating!

How do I get Selenium to open it in a new tab like when I run it manually?!  I can't see anything in the desiredcapabilities options so am assuming this is a setting locally on the machine...?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not support tabs, opening popups in new window is expected behaviour, at least as far as I know. Anyway, you can probably build something using the [Actions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class to send [keystrokes](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html) using the sendKeys from actions.

Comment: After a lot of digging I had to give in on this one, I've started using the driver.switchTo() method to find the window I want.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in my code, and it works. the clicked link opens in a new tab. 
it could be something to do with Selenium version. 
Try with Selenium version 3.141.59
and ChromeDriver version 76.0.3809.68.