# Selenium - IE driver : click on a link defined in js with _blank do nothing

Tags: selenium, selenium-iedriver

I test a site where they are links that open in a new tab. It's working manually for IE, FireFox and Chrome and with Selenium for FireFox and Chrome but not for IE, it's do nothing and there are no error.
I inspected the code
HTML :

```
<a id="idA"></a>
```

JS :

```
$("#idA").on("click", function () {
    window.open("urlToOpen", "_blank");
}
```

Java :

```
(definition of the driver)  
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","pathToMyDriverIE");                           
    InternetExplorerOptions internetExplorerOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
    internetExplorerOptions.setCapability("RequireWindowFocus", true);
    internetExplorerOptions.setCapability("EnablePersistentHover", true);
    internetExplorerOptions.setCapability("EnableNativeEvents", true);
    internetExplorerOptions.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
    internetExplorerOptions.setCapability("ie.ensureCleanSession", true);
    internetExplorerOptions.setCapability("enableElementCacheCleanup", true);
    internetExplorerOptions.destructivelyEnsureCleanSession();
    internetExplorerOptions.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
    internetExplorerOptions.setCapability("UnexpectedAlertBehavior", UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
    internetExplorerOptions.setCapability("IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings", true);         
    internetExplorerOptions.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(internetExplorerOptions); 


(function to click on the link)
public void clickOnLink(boolean withJs){
    WebElement W = driver.findElement(By.id("idA"));
    if(withJs){
         ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", W);
    }
    else{
        W.click();
    }
}
```

I think to do it manually, in opening a new window (because I need to interact with after and it's difficult to do it with IE in a new tab), but I can't get the link defined in JS. There are no problem without _blank.
Someone has an idea?
Selenium : 3.11.0 ; InternetExplorerDriver : 3.9 (32 bits) ; JDK8
Thanks in advance.

Comment: apparantly my problem is not new [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477853/selenium-webdriver-opening-links-in-new-window-when-manually-it-opens-in-new-tab?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some search and tests, it seems IE driver have big problem to open new tabs or window. I use so a new WebDriver like that :

```
public static void clicOnLink(){
    //driver = WebDriver in use
    WebElement w = driver.findElement(By.id("idA"));
    w.click();
    if(DriverIsIE && driver.getWindowHandles().size()==1){
        if(w.getTagName().equals("a") && (w.getAttribute("href")!=null && !w.getAttribute("href").isEmpty())){
            openWithNewDriver();
        }
        else{
            String source = driver.getPageSource();
            int s0 = source.indexOf("$(\"#idA\").on(\"click\"");
            String s2 = source.substring(s0,source.indexOf("});"),s0);
            String[] ss = s2.substring(s2.indexOf("window.open")).split(",");
            String urlToOpen = ss[0].replaceAll("\"","").replace("window.open(","").replace(")","");
            openWithNewDriver(urlToOpen);
        }
    }
}

public static void openWithNewDriver(String url){
    WebDriver driver2 = setUpDriver();//definition of the driver
    if(url!=null && !url.isEmpty()){
        driver2.get(url);
    }
    //ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//body")));
    //to do something on the new window
    driver2.close();
}
```

If it's be helpful for someone in the future.